# Is memory allocated when a declaration is made in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory

When I look at a c++ declaration and definition, as shown below:

```
int i;
i = 2;
```

the way I understand how memory is allocated is that the computer:

- first, reads `int i`
- then, finds enough memory to hold one integer and denotes that memory with the identifier "i"
- then, reads `i = 2`
- then, stores the value 2 in the memory with the identifier "i"

However, I am running into an issue when trying to understand Javascript declarations and definitions. Consider the code shown below:

```
var i;
i = 2;
```

When the computer first reads `var i`, it will not know how much memory to allocate as the computer does not yet know that the value to be stored is a number.

My question is, what happens when I write `var i`. Is some memory allocated, and when the computer later reads `i = 2`, then does it reallocate a sufficient amount of memory?

Please let me know what you think and if you have any good resources, let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your understanding of C++ is incorrect. The compiler reads the whole file at compile time. Then decide what it will do later: At runtime, I'll grow the stack by the size of an integer. Or, it may decide, I'll use a register for that. Or make it a constant in the code segment if it sees it's never modified. It can even decide to remove it altogether while optimizing out the code around it.

Comment: Javascript is written in C++. So you can start thinking about how to implement something like javascript in C++. At the C++ level a variable in javascript is just a data structure that has a pointer that can point to the thing it contains. When something is assigned to that variable `i = 2` an object is created (in this case `2`) and is then assigned to the data structure with the name `i` and the value pointing to `2`. How can `i` contain different types of objects? In javascript everything including numbers, strings, functions etc are subclasses of the Object class - it's just polymorphism

Comment: @slebetman number, string, and boolean primitives are **not** objects, and not subclasses of Object.

Comment: @Pointy Not at the javascript level. But at the C++ level one way to implement a slot that can hold anything is polymorphism. You still need a single superclass to hold the value of primitives and objects. You can of course have two value slots one for references and one for actual values but in practice you'd only do this to numbers and maybe booleans but still strings need to be a pointer to a string object. I've not seen any such implementation however.

Comment: ECMAScript doesn't define implementation details so there can be no definitive answer for how a particular piece of code might be implemented.

Comment: @slebetman I'm not so sure about that, but in any case what JavaScript primitives are in any particular implementation is unspecified, and even if they're "objects" in the runtime, that they're objects that are subclassed from the JavaScript Object base class seems even more speculative.

Comment: I suggest you read the textbook "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs". Languages with dynamic typing have much more in common with the Lisp family than C.